# i just loading the text file into table ...... then i got error like this

Tags: mysql

Error

SQL query:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/sharma/Desktop/New.txt' INTO TABLE FIELDS FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

MySQL said: Documentation

## 2 - File '/home/sharma/Desktop/New.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)

Comment: Well, it happens because file is not found, obviously.

Comment: @zerkms You should be a fortune teller :)

Comment: And if it exists, it must exist in the remote side. (When not using `mysqlimport` with `--local`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the file exists and that you & the mysql server user have access to read it.

Comment: I will not upvote you since you already have great rep points value ;-) What about new "devil" badge for the ones who got 666, 6666 and 66666 for bronze, silver and gold badges accordingly?

Comment: @zerkms: It's a real mission to keep it at 666. I need to downvote so often to keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is located on server host, try to load it without the LOCALE keyword.